# How to add gridlines to d3 realTimeChartMulti?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to adapt Bo Ericsson's D3 realTimeChartMulti example to a particular use, and I need to add a gridline where each category appears. I have not been able to figure out how to do that using his code.

https://bl.ocks.org/boeric/6a83de20f780b42fadb9

Does anyone have any idea how to do it? Everything I've tried (manipulating the D3 y axis to add ticks(5) would be the simplest alternative, as a start) causes the display to stop rendering altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a gridline is setting the `innerTickSize()` method (`tickSizeInner` in v4/5), which in your case would be:

```
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left").innerTickSize(-width);
```

Then, you can style it the way you want in the CSS by selecting a `line` with the `y` and `axis` classes (here I'm using a dashed line). Alternatively, you can apply the style straight to the group selection (append the axis first, and then append the circles).

Finally, you can see that the circles are *behind* the gridline, which is not a very elegant design. You can change that by changing the order of the appended elements.

Here is the forked code: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/2eaffbb3437acb62f66a7b6cb85bf435/3042a5357cbc703dcf102c733b7b5772b82d744c

Comment: Thank you Gerardo for the very elegant answer. It was exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!